# How to add/remove applications from "File and Folders" inside "Security and Privacy" -> Privacy Tab

Tags: macos, permission, system-settings, privacy

[image]

How to remove these bunch of files from here.
I use VS code, when I debug a program it asks for this permission that a file that is created while debugging wants to access your Document folder. And every time I have to allow it and then those files end up in Privacy -> "Files and Folders".

[image]

Comment: This is only for your Desktop, Downloads, and Documents folders.  Can you direct VS Code to save these projects in a different folder?

Answer (score 2):

Run

```
tccutil reset SystemPolicyDocumentsFolder
tccutil reset SystemPolicyDownloadsFolder
tccutil reset SystemPolicyDesktopFolder
```

They are case sensitive.

Sources:

- https://www.felix-schwarz.org/blog/2018/08/new-apple-event-apis-in-macos-mojave "Configuration Profiles" section.
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-deviceconfig-macosprivacyaccesscontrolitem?view=graph-rest-beta
- https://github.com/chernandezba/zesarux/blob/873f31b9db563369039909d4d841e004fd77c443/src/docs/mac_os_catalina_users_permissions.txt
- https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf

If the above is too cumbersome,

```
tccutil reset
```

which resets all permissions across all profiles.

tccutil.py is outdated and even after disabling SIP, it will not give meaningful info about the database:

```
/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db
```

- https://github.com/jacobsalmela/tccutil/issues/18#issuecomment-655420138

Comment: To reset everything, it is `tccutil reset` not `rest`